# Cutting down some MYSQL results.

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need some help cutting out a line from a path that's returned from my database.

The results of "ImagePath" in the database return /share/images/Gif/XXX/XXXXXX/ (XX being filler for whatever is actually returned)

I need to cut off "/share/images/" from the results of ImagePath so I would just get /Gif/XXX/XXXXXX/

The reason is that this instance of the database is one way > updated from another server that has a different location for the images so I don't really want to go through and delete those lines from the database since the next time it's updated it would revert to the other path I just want to cut out those lines from the results.

```
<?php

        define('INCLUDE_CHECK',1);
        require "connect.php";
        require_once("class.php");

        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

         // $product_id = intval($_GET['product']); //no default
            $UPC = intval($_GET['upc']); //no default


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT ImagePath, AlphaName, brand_name, FullName, ingredients FROM Images, Products WHERE ImageType='gif' AND images.ProductID = products.ProductID AND ViewCode='CF' AND products.UPC = '$UPC'");
        $count=mysql_affected_rows();

        $objJSON=new mysql2json(); 
        print(trim($objJSON->getJSON($result,$count)));


            /* disconnect from the db */
            @mysql_close($link);

        ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can always do [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
select substring(imagepath, 14) as ImagePath...
```

Or [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), if your `ImagePath` values aren't all the same:

```
select replace(imagepath, '/share/images/', '') as ImagePath...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with PHP use can [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/str_replace).

```
$image = str_replace('/share/images/', '', $db_row['imagepath']);
```

If you want to do it in MySQL use `REPLACE()` (my recommendation).

```
SELECT REPLACE(imagepath, '/share/images/', '') AS imagepath FROM table;
```

**Note**: Although it will *resolve itself* over time, it's unintuitive to do this in the code. You should update your records directly. Especially if your data been migrated from an older server configuration. Fix at the source. Otherwise you're patching.

Comment: Why would you use replace instead of substr?

Comment: Just a habit I suppose. Might be faster in PHP, hmmm... As far as SQL, `REPLACE()` is more universal across the flavors.

Comment: @Jason McCreary - The other server is a Live server maintained by a company and updated daily by them for a monthly fee. This instance is for a local implementation and so the path "/share/images" will never change. I could technically just put the files in /share/images on my local implementation but I feel it's cleaner to not try and replicate the path just because I'm to lazy too shape the results.

Comment: Fair enough. Then the PHP example I provided should suit you. Per **Elijakim**, you could also use `substr()` if your paths are uniform (i.e. start with `/share/images/`).